# Como dividir en diferentes archivos las hojas de un archivo excel y renombrarlos

Tags: python, excel, vb

estoy intentando programar con python algo que hago en excel programando con vb.

Lo que busco es crear tantos archivos como hojas tiene un archivo excel.
Y que cada uno de los nuevos archivos se nombre con el nombre de la hoja+nombre del archivo incial.

Después se guarden todos los archivos nuevos.

El código en vb es este:

```
Sub ArchivoHojas()
Dim mi_libro As String
mi_libro = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each hojas In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

hojas.Copy
Filename = ThisWorkbook.Name
Filename1 = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, ".") - 1)
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=hojas.Name & Filename1 & ".xlsx"
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Por ahora lo que he conseguido con python es hacerlo con una única hoja:

```
import openpyxl
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet', codepage='utf8', engine='openpyxl')
grabar = pd.ExcelWriter( sheet_name and workbook_name and '.xlsx')
df.to_excel(grabar,'sheet')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes abrir el Excel con un `pd.ExcelFile(archivo)`, y este nuevo objeto va a tener el atributo `sheet_names`, con el nombre de cada hoja. Luego lo puedes recorrer con un `for each` y guardar cada archivo como deseas.

```
import pandas as pd

workbook = "file.xlsx"
df_sheets = pd.ExcelFile(workbook, engine="openpyxl")

for elem in df_sheets.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(workbook, engine="openpyxl", sheet_name=elem)
    df.to_excel(f"{elem} {workbook}.xlsx")
```

Solo como observación, en tu línea:

```
sheet_name and workbook_name and '.xlsx'
```

El operador `and` en python **no sirve para "sumar" o añadir.** Sino que es un operador *lógico*. Es decir, evalúa que dos expresiones sean verdadero, `condicion_a and condicion_b` te da `True` si ambas condiciones son `True`. No es que las "sume". Por eso lo reemplacé con un [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).